# sysRq fine control

Tags: kernel

I just found out, that I can enable sysrq magic keys temporarily by

`# echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`  or  `# sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1`

To enable these changes at boot time one has to create config file in the **sysctl.d** directory (e.g. **/etc/sysctl.d/90-sysrq.conf**) with this line:

**kernel.sysrq = 1**

So setting **/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq** to **1** enables the sysrq magic keys, setting it to **0** disables it.

By default the value is set to **176**. What does that exactly mean in terms of sysrq functionality and what other values are possible and how do they differ in functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` , it should be informative.
So 176 means

16 - enable sync command

32 - enable remount read-only

128 - allow reboot/poweroff

16+32+128 = 176